# I want to make a link unclickable for the first 10 seconds and then make it clickable

Tags: javascript, html

On my website I want to make a link unclickable for the first 10 seconds after the page loads and then make it clickable like a normal link after.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create CSS class with .disabled and add set it to link.
2. In onload event, use setTimeout to remove the class "disabled" and set the time to 10sec.

```js
window.onload = function (e) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.querySelector(".disabled").classList.remove("disabled");
  }, 10000);
};
```

```css
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <a href="https://google.com" class="disabled">Google</a>
  </body>
</html>
```